# Create a submit button when I press Add, multiple events under one button

Tags: c#, wpf

Any idea how I could make a click event create another button with different click event?

I have a WPF app to make using EF. So I'm stuck at the part where I need to press button "Add" which will freeze other buttons and then create another button "Submit" with code for adding data to the table. I have tried some advice from msdn, but it doesn't work. Here is the code (previously in XAML added a button named b1):

```
public partial class RoutedEventAddRemoveHandler {
void MakeButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button b2 = new Button();
    b2.Content = "New Button";
    // Associate event handler to the button. You can remove the event  
    // handler using "-=" syntax rather than "+=".
    b2.Click  += new RoutedEventHandler(Onb2Click);
    root.Children.Insert(root.Children.Count, b2);
    DockPanel.SetDock(b2, Dock.Top);
    text1.Text = "Now click the second button...";
    b1.IsEnabled = false;
}
void Onb2Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    text1.Text = "New Button (b2) Was Clicked!!";
}
```

I even tried the most obvious solution to simply create another button with click event directly in click event.

Comment: I would not create your button on the fly but immediately and manipulate its visibility and or the fact that it is enabled yes or no instead of going through all this trouble.

Comment: Why create a new button when you can have the submit button in your xaml with visible=false and just change it's visibility to true when needed?

Comment: What is "root" variable?

Comment: delete all that and use proper XAML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend an alternative approach and put the submitbutton in your xaml code right away but make it so that it is invisible and disabled.

Then in the event handler you simply have to make it visible and enable it.

Your event handler that handles the submit, the dynamic creation of the button, hooking it in the form and such can all be avoided and don't have to be done at runtime.

This will result in a lot better readable code and maintainable code than your original approach unless you have a very good reason for it.

Comment: Awesome, that solved my problem without any unneeded complications. I set the visibility to collapsed so that button doesn't take any space..Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

I have done the following coding and it is working for me

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button oButton = new Button();
            oButton.Name = "btnMessage";
            oButton.Content = "Message Show";
            oButton.Height = 50;
            oButton.Width = 50;
            oButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(oButton_Click);
            //root is a stack panel
            root.Children.Insert(root.Children.Count, oButton);
            DockPanel.SetDock(oButton, Dock.Top);

        }

        void oButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello World !");
        }
```